# Sinch onShouldSendPushData is not firing

Tags: android, sinch

Sinch onShouldSendPushData fuction never gets called. I am trying to push the message if the receiver is not active. But the problem is This function never gets called. Whats should I do ?

Comment: Is the receiver defined in your manifest?  Show the relevant parts of the manifest.  If it's a programmatically added receiver then show the code.

Comment: I only added the service in the manifest which is related to Sinch.

Comment: <service android:name=".SinchService"/>

Comment: Thing is I'm using Parse for Push notification

Comment: Thanks, I know now what I was doing wrong. 
Still I have one question.. Can I know whether to send a push message without activating the Sinch Push service ? Cause I want to do the Push using Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do push using Parse please set the following function to false: `setSupportManagedPush(false)`.

This is from the Sinch documentation that can be found here:
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#pushnotifications

Hope this helps!